# Why are midichlorians not mentioned when talking about Sabine in Ahsoka?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, jedi, midichlorians, ahsoka-series

Ahsoka mentions talent is a part of becoming a Jedi, but isn't a minimum amount of midichlorians needed to become a Jedi? I could be mistaken, but this is the impression I got from Star Wars I, so I thought they aren't force sensitive otherwise. Maybe this is explained in a previous show why she would still be trying to be a Jedi. If midichlorians aren't needed, then it does sound like anyone could be a Jedi, like Sabine asked.

Comment: The impression that I got was exactly the opposite—that talent (midi-chlorians or otherwise) is not needed, even though it evidently helps. That is why Huyang told Sabine that she was less talented than any youngling he had ever met.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're saying. If talent isn't needed, why did the robot say that, cuz it said she was bad. So it would sound like talent is needed. But I'm more talking about what Ahsoka was saying

Comment: Huyang was implying that even someone who had less *talent* (inherent potential) for the Force than any Jedi he had ever met could still progress as a Jedi if they trained.

Comment: I thought the Huyang was telling her to give up. Anyways, I'm asking why midichlorians was left out of the conversation, as in is it necessary.

Comment: The Jedi Guide makes it clear that you can want to be a Jedi all you like, but if you ain't got the inherent ability (as shown by your midi-chlorian count), then you're not going to be able to use the Force.

Comment: Note also that midi-chlorians show up in the blood of Force sensitives. It's not 100% clear if they're *essential in using the Force* or more needed to *sense what the Living Force wants you to do*.

Comment: @Valorum - "The Jedi Path: A Manual for Students of the Force"? That's less canon than the holiday special under the mighty mouse. Anyway, Ahsoka is pretty clear that she thinks that while not everyone has the same talent for the Force, everyone can at least theoretically learn to access it to some degree.

Comment: @Adamant - That violently conflicts with established canon.

Comment: If it was already known she has enough midichlorians so it wasn't needed to be brought up, ok. But it would then seem a silly question asking why everyone doesn't use it. I don't think Ahsoka makes it clear everyone can learn to access it, she just says talent is a factor. She could have been just ignoring Sabines silly question that everyone could use it, meaning while born force sensitivity is needed, talent does play a part. It would sound odd to me if she means by 'talent' a level of 'force sensitivity ' though.

Comment: @Valorum - I guess you need to be prepared for the violence of the mouse, then, because that seems to be where they are going. But that was what the original idea was, as well: "Kasdan: The Force was available to anyone who could hook into it? Lucas: Yes, everybody can do it. K: Not just the Jedi? L: It's just the Jedi who take the time to do it." Frankly, if the Force flows through everyone, as Ahsoka says, it makes a lot of sense that everyone has *some* Force potential, but someone like Sabine has to try a lot harder to get to a fraction of what Rey or Luke does without trying.

Comment: To me, this would come across as clunky and unnecessary. Sabine and Huyang both know that Sabine has a low midi-chlorian count. Why would either of them say it out loud? For the audience's benefit? *We* already know that too.

Comment: Saying the force flows through all I thought was just like obi wan saying it's everywhere, doesn't mean anyone can use it.

Comment: Maybe because [people don't walk to talk about it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnWoM.png)? Just saying...

Comment: @F1Krazy agreed, and not only that: midichlorians are one of Lucas' stupider ideas, so anything that sidesteps the question is more than welcome!

Comment: @Machavity that's the real answer in my opinion! ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer**: They're not mentioned because they're not relevant to the discussion.

**Long Answer**: Nowhere is it ever stated that there's a specific minimum M-Count required to become a Jedi. It is however stated in 'Ahsoka' that the Jedi Order of the late Republic period would have rejected a candidate with a low natural aptitude with the force.

Whether one chooses to directly equate that to a candidate's M-Count, and by extension the Order's primary means of measuring aptitude is not an entirely unreasonable assumption, but for now it's still just an assumption. It should be noted though that we did see the council subject Anakin to a variety of tests to gauge his aptitude and suitability, not just a blood test. On top of that: Anakin had one of, if not the all time highest M-Count of any Jedi ever, and the council initially rejected him based on his age alone . . . only to un-reject him because Obi-Wan was just going to up and train him regardless.

Point being that not only is M-Count not the be-all end-all of Jedi candidacy, but who the council would and would not prefer to train is not the same thing as who can and can not be trained.

As for what Lucas himself had to say on the subject; here's an edited snippet of an interview he gave in 1977, as published in [J. W Rinzler's The Making of Star Wars](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=AKqMW5ChgScC&q=The%20Force%20is%20always%20there%2C%20however.%20Anyone%20who%20studied%20and%20worked%20hard%20could%20learn%20it.#v=snippet&q=The%20Force%20is%20always%20there%2C%20however.%20Anyone%20who%20studied%20and%20worked%20hard%20could%20learn%20it.&f=false). For context, it was done mostly "in character" and mostly off the top of his head for the benefit of the licencing people, just so they had some common background lore to work from (whether they actually used it or not is another matter): -

> "The Force is really a way of feeling; it’s a way of being with life" . . . "The Force gives you the power to have extrasensory perception and to be able to see things and hear things, read minds and levitate things. It is said that certain creatures are born with a higher awareness of the Force than humans. Their brains are different; they have more midi-chlorians in their cells." . . . "The Force is a perception of the reality that exists around us. You have to come to learn it. It’s not something you just get. It takes many, many years." . . . "The Force is always there, however. Anyone who studied and worked hard could learn it."

Which is essentially what was said by Kanan in 'Trials of the Darksaber', and reiterated by Ahsoka in 'Time to Fly'. Midi-chlorians are just a biological mechanism present in all cellular life that facilitates communication with the force; having an abundance may give a person more innate talent in using the force and are thus easier to train, but the force exists within, and is created by all living things. Anyone *can* train to feel and wield the force if they work at it enough, study, and of course approach it with the right mindset. It's just really really difficult.